# c# How to use user database everywhere

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, database, heidisql

I'm working on a program that include user log-in and sign-up. I'm using MySQL with HeidiSQL app which is free. I can use my app in my own pc but when I start it an another pc it says there isn't any user like that or it doesn't even connect to database. How can i achieve this?

My connection string is:

```
public MySqlConnection mysqlbaglan = new MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=x;Uid=root;Pwd='';");
```

Comment: How do you connect? Can you show the connection string used?

Comment: public MySqlConnection mysqlbaglan = new MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=x;Uid=root;Pwd='';");

Comment: You are connecting to 'localhost', your database is on your PC. You are basically sending mail to your mailbox and wonder why your friend in another city don't find your mail in his mailbox. You have to tell your friend to come to get it in your mailbox (with access) or tell him to get it in another location that is  not your mailbox and accessible for him

Comment: Please edit your question to add new information. When reading, it is easy to miss if this is only in the comments.

Comment: @Calimero Should I buy a server then?

Comment: You could configure your PC and database so your friend can connect to it (with a different connection string that tells him where to look), but in any case your database is unaccessible when your PC is turned off. If you need your database to be available at all time, and don't want your friend operation on the database to kill your PC performance (and your PC actions to make the database slow), a dedicated machine would probably be better.